# Not Able to open Chrome browser in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

Not Able to open Chrome browser in Selenium.

Here is the code:

```
package toolsqa;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;     
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\MR049860\\Documents\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");    
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();    
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");     
        driver.manage().window().maximize();     
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at toolsqa.TestChrome.main(TestChrome.java:14)
```

Comment: could you reformat your code in the post and also point which is line 14

Comment: Do you have guava jar in classpath or dependency?

Comment: try downloading new chrome driver, and paste it in D: drive.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

While mentioning the **`Key`** and **`Value`** within **`System.setProperty()`** you have to escape the back slashes `(\\)`. Hence, you need to change the line :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:Path\chromedriver.exe");
```

To :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\absolute_path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
```

Comment: Update the question with your current code and current error stack trace. Your previous error was definitely with `System.setProperty()`

Comment: Can you go through my Answer once more, the error seems the same, you need to escape the back slashes.

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\absolute_path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
I have used the same format but its not displaying in the code